# javaFX erro SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: javafx, webcam

I am working on javaFX application and I need to open webcam.
I am using com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam lib and got this error

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"
>
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder

My code is simple:

```
  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    webcam=Webcam.getDefault();
    webcam.setViewSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
    webcam.open();
}
```

Anyone can tell me what is the problem because this code works in Swing but not in javaFX.

Thanks

Comment: Have you added SL4J as a dependency? Are you using Gradle/Maven? Can you post your build config?

Comment: i add to lib bridj-0.6.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
webcam-capture-0.3.10
i use netbeans i do not know anything about maven

Comment: SLF4J is a logging facade and the warning/error is telling you that you don't have an implementation on the classpath. Note that this warning/error shouldn't stop the application from running.

Comment: i am using macbook problem was from OS its work fine in windows

Comment: Just add a dependency to slf4j-simple in addition to slf4j-api.